# Как получить доступ к уведомлениям status bar из приложения

Tags: android, push-уведомления

В моём приложении настроена интеграция с Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), на телефон приходят уведомления, которые успешно попадают в службу `FirebaseMessagingService`.  После поступления уведомления из FCM служба создаёт уведомление для телефона и отправляет его в `status bar`. Если пользователь тапает по уведомлению в шторке, в приложение приходит `intent`, который попадает либо в `onCreate`, либо в `onNewIntent` в зависимости от того выключено приложение или нет. Для случая когда пользователь уже открыл приложение и смотрит контент поступление нового уведомления обрабатывается через `BroadcastReceiver`. Всё работает прекрасно, за исключением 1 случая, когда **пришло уведомление** и **приложение** при этом **было полностью выключено** (т.е. не находится в backstack приложений, не перекрыто другим и т.д.), а пользователь решил **открыть приложение по ярлыку**, а не через `status bar`. 
 Как в таком случае поймать уведомление из `status bar` и получить доступ к данным, хранящимся в его `intent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Есть 2 типа нотификаций](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) - `data` и `notification`. В случае с `notification` - все как у тебя, он у тебя видимо и используется. В случае с `data` обрабатывать пришедший пуш нужно самому, т.е. ты сам создаешь нотификацию и все данные есть. Эти данные можно добавить в `Intent` и тогда их можно будет получить при нажатии на пуш в открытом Activity, например.

В указанном случае нужно указывать уникальный ID нотификации и кешировать ее скажем в базу данных при создании. При этом обязательно стоит отлавливать не была ли закрыта нотификация, т.к. адекватных способов получить все текущие нотификации нет

Comment: спасибо, у меня используется data, со стороны back end уведомление формируется в формате Json и отправляется по протоколу HTTP в приложение. Дальше уведомление попадает в службу и отрабатывает так как указано в вопросе, однако в вашем ответе не понятно как решить данную проблему. Вся соль заключает именно в том что пользователь не нажимает на уведомление, а BroadcastReciever заработает только при рабочем приложении.